# Angular ng-options returning index instead of object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my ng options

```
 <select ng-init="vm.tutors = vm.tutors || 0" ng-model="vm.tutors"    ng-options="tutors.fullname as tutor  for (tutor, fullname) in vm.tutors" class="form-control"></select>
```

and below is my object

vm.tutors
 [Object { fullname="NAME"}, Object { fullname="NAME2"}}]

What is the reason I keep getting the index instead of the actual value

Comment: Can you provide plunker/jsfiddle to make it easier to answer your question?

Comment: also, since it hasn't been explicitly mentioned so far:  This is not an appropriate use for `ng-init`.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting the index is because you have some syntax/concept issues.

Your code looks like it needs some love so here is a decent example of the proper way to do this:

Controller:

```
$scope.vm.tutors = [{fullname: "NAME"}, {fullname: "NAME2"}];
$scope.vm.selectedTutor = ""; // you can assign a value if you would like to have an option preselected.
```

HTML:
    // in this example tutor.fullname is the Label and Value for the select option.

```
<select ng-model="vm.selectedTutor" ng-options="tutor.fullname for tutor in vm.tutors" ></select>
```

Now when you select an option the value will be assigned to $scope.vm.selectedTutor and it wont break your array.

Alternatively you can setup a key value pair relationship with your select options like so:

Controller:

```
$scope.vm.tutors = [{fullname: "NAME", id: "0"}, {fullname: "NAME2", id:"1"}];
```

HTML:
    // in this example tutor.id is the Value and tutor.fullname is the Label for the select option

```
<select ng-model="vm.selectedTutor" ng-options="tutor.id as tutor.fullname for tutor in vm.tutors" ></select>
```

I hope this helps you understand what is going on here a little better, also [HERE is a link to the AngularJS documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)