# Automatically select the right option element with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an AngularJS application (1.4) and right now I'm working on a dropdown menu to select different pages.

The problem is that when I select a page in the menu and I go to that page, I would like to have the name of the page automatically selected on the dropdown menu and this is not happening.

Here's the code:

```
<select ng-options="menu_voice.name for menu_voice in menu_voices track by menu_voice.url" ng-model='selectedOption' ng-change="changeLink()">
</select>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.changeLink = function(){
    $state.go($scope.selectedOption.url);
};

$scope.menu_voices = [
    {
        "url": 'account.company',
        "name": 'Company'
    },
    {
        "url": 'account.billing',
        "name": 'Billing'
    }
    ...
];
```

Finally, since I'm using angular-ui-router and all of those pages are nested views, in each controller of the nested view I have this line of code:

```
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.menu_voices[x];
```

Where x is the number of the menu voice I want to select.

I can change page, but everytime in the dropdown menu the selected voice is the blank one.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I made a small modification to my original answer as I could not get it to work with the "track by" clause using angularjs v1.4.

HTML: // url is now the value and name is the label of the select options

```
<select ng-options="menu_voice.url as menu_voice.name for menu_voice in menu_voices" ng-model="selectedOption">
```

Controller:

to preselect the option you would assign "selectedOption" the url.

```
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.menu_voices[x].url;
```

Now for the change link you can do one of two things here

```
$scope.changeLink = function(){
    $state.go($scope.selectedOption);
};
```

OR

```
$scope.changeLink = function(url){
    $state.go(url);
};
```

coupled with this:

```
<select ng-change="changeLink(selectedOption)" ...>
```

[here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11489/) using angularjs v1.4

[Here is a reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369177/angular-ng-options-returning-index-instead-of-object-value/40369550#40369550) to a similar question that may help you understand what is happening here.